# Getting JS-variable from AJAX loaded content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, variables, plugins

I know it's not possible to call an jQuery Plugin within an `.ajax()` loaded page, the only way is to write a function in the parent page and call this function in the `function(data)` part of the AJAX request. This works in general, but I'm stuck because my function needs a variable from the loaded content to work correctly and whatever I'm trying, I can't get the variable from the loaded content into the parent function, see my example:

This is my function:

```
function doPaginate(maxpage) {
    jQuery("#demo5").paginate({
        count: maxpage
    });
}​
```

This is my `jQuery.ajax()` request:

```
function loadProfileTab(tab, ownerinfo) {
    jQuery.post("./profile_ajax.php", {
        task: 'profiletab',
        v: tab,
        user_id: ownerinfo
    }, function(data) {
        jQuery("#profile_content_wrapper").html(data);
        doPaginate(maxpage);
    });
}​
```

What I'm trying is now to get the variable `maxpage` from the PHP loaded content into the function `doPaginate(maxpage)` *within the AJAX request*.

I know some workarounds, in example start a request first to get the result of `$maxpage`, then start a request again to use this result in the new request, but it seems to be not the "nicest" solution.

Can someone lead me to a better solution please? Or is it just impossible what I'm trying in my code example above?

Best regards!

Comment: What's the response from the AJAX call like? I mean the value for `data`.

Comment: If the loaded JS defines the variable in the toplevel scope, it should be visible to your function.

Comment: the response is like a complete php template, including a members list inclusive design. Now i'm trying to introduce a jQuery-AJAX-pagination into this loaded content, 10 members each page, but therefore I have to count the pages within the PHP file since every member have an individual amount of contacts for this list, that's why I need this **maxpage** to generate the pagination plugin correctly.

Comment: Where/How is maxpage defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the value for the `maxpage` variable as a hidden field in the HTML returned by AJAX and use **jQuery** to find the value, something like this.

```
var data = '<html><head></head><body><form><div>Ble</div><input id="maxpage" type="hidden" value="10"/></form></body></html>';
var maxpage = $(data).find('#maxpage').val();
console.log(maxpage);
alert(maxpage);
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GAmwk/1/) for this code.
​